# AngularJS routing not working with cshtml

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs, razor

I'm trying to create a single page application using AngularJS and MVC4.

The problem i'm facing is the routing concept within my app.js file is not working with cshtml.
My app.js code is as follows,

```
      var ToDoApp = angular.module("ToDoApp",[]).config(function ($routeProvider) {
             $routeProvider.when('/MyArea/job', {controller: 'ListCtrl',templateUrl: '/MyArea/job/list' })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
     }); 



    ToDoApp.controller('ListCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.item = "harun";
     })
```

I have an index.cshtml where i'm trying to render my partial view. The index.cshtml code is as follows,

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
 }

 <h2>Index</h2>

 <script src="~/Areas/Security/Scripts/app.js"></script>

 <div data-ng-view=""></div>
```

The list.cshtml (partial view) code is as follows,

```
@{   
   Layout = null;
}

<label>{{item}}</label>
```

I've done the same concept working with simple html files.

Please help me out if i've done anything wrong.

Comment: is your controller being getting called ?

Comment: You also need to put a `.when` for when the user is at index.html. So .when('/', {controller: 'IndexCtrl',templateUrl: '/index.cshtml' })

Comment: @Ajaybeniwal that's not needed when you refer to the controller already in your router.

Comment: You need to check if `'/MyArea/job/list'` is correct. Remember that in MVC4 application, the url should point to a controller's action function which returns a view

Comment: @Ajay beniwal, Only the index action is being hit. The control is not going to the partial action. Actually i have an area called security and ~/security/job/ is my path to index.cshtml and ~/security/job/list is the path to List.cshtml.

Comment: @bicycle, please check my comment to Ajay.

Comment: start by verifying that you can make a get-request to the template-uri, as others have pointed out. what does firebug/fiddler/whatever tell you? 404?

Comment: @marko, i've checked that no 404.